# ASP.NET Core No Longer Reading PUT After Upgrade From 7 to 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-8

I recently upgraded my fairly simple Angular 17 & ASP.NET Core app from .NET 7 to 8.  The calls to PUT just stopped including the model/body for reasons I couldn't understand.

The calls from Angular are simple...

```
this.http.put<DetailsModelBase>(`${this.getBaseApiUrl()}${record.id}`, record)
      .pipe(tap(model => {
        record.timestamp = model.timestamp;
      }));
```

And the controller methods are also pretty vanilla...

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, TDetails viewModel)
{
    Debug.Assert(id == viewModel.Id);
    var record = await Table.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id);
    return await ValidateAndUpdateModel(viewModel, record);
}
```

This code was absolutely working for years with no problems prior to upgrading to .NET 8.  However, after upgrading, the TDetails model was uninitialized.  No properties had been set, as if it was new'd and that was it.

I couldn't find anything in the release notes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#authentication-and-authorization) to indicate why this would be happening.

Also, I was one version behind on Angular before this started, so I updated, and it was still happening.  In other words, I've reproduced this issue on both Angular 16 and 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that because an Angular PUT sends the model data as a JSON object in the body of the request, rather than the form data that a POST request uses, you have to tell ASP.NET to pull it from the body with the `[FromBody]` attribute on the action's parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody]TDetails viewModel)
```

That is the only change needed to fix this.

I hope this helps someone else.  I believe I googled and SO-searched this very thoroughly and couldn't find anyone else reporting this issue.  I also couldn't find any details on what changed in ASP.NET 8 that caused this to start happening.

Comment: If anyone can comment on what exactly changed in .NET 8, or better yet point to something in the docs, I think that would be hugely appreciated.  I couldn't find even a scrap of info on the subject.

Comment: As I remember when you send PUT/POST request, you need to add a data model into the request body. Usually API can detect it and resolve on it's own, then grab the model from body. For some reason your API got confused and was expecting to get a model from somewhere else or DI(if you use minimal API). Sorry, no links to documentations.